# Compiler can't see argument

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am new to C++ and want to play around with classes.

## My code

In my world there are heros and swords. Heros carry swords. This shouldn't be too hard.

```cpp
// Defining swords                                                                                                                                 
class Sword
{
  // The most important thing about a sword is its length.                                                                                         
  int lenght;
public:
  // only constructor and destructor                                                                                                               
  Sword(int swordlength){
    lenght = swordlength;
  };
  ~Sword(){};
};

// defining heros (as people with magic swords)                                                                                                    
class Hero
{
  Sword magic_sword;
public:
  // each hero gets a standard sword                                                                                                               
  Hero(){
    int meters = 2;
    magic_sword = Sword(meters);
  };
  ~Hero(){};
};

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

## What the compiler thinks about it

When I compile this code (`g++ hero.cpp`) I get an error:

```
 In constructor 'Hero::Hero()':
20:9: error: no matching function for call to 'Sword::Sword()'
20:9: note: candidates are:
8:3: note: Sword::Sword(int)
8:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
2:7: note: constexpr Sword::Sword(const Sword&)
2:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

## What I think the problem is

Compiling the code with `clang++` also fails, but the error message is not as explicit, so I won't post it here.

It seems that calling the constructor `Sword(meters)` failed because I provided 0 instead of 1 argument. But I clearly gave it an argument (`meters`), so I guess I am missunderstanding something here.

What is my mistake and what can I do about it?

Comment: Hero() : magic_sword(2) { /* your ctor */ } . You need to construct the sword when constructing the hero. When it enters the code in the ctor, the Hero fields are already constructed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Hero` always has a `Sword`.

That means that, the moment the class is instantiated, before the `Hero::Hero` constructor starts running, it already has to have a "default" `Sword`. The compiler is complaining that it doesn't know how to make such a "default" `Sword`.

Now, there's multiple ways you can address this:

### Using initialization lists

In the definition of a constructor, you can specify *how* your object's members should be *initialized* (*before* the actual constructor runs). This is different from *assigning* them a new value in the constructor's body (which happens in your example). To do this, specify a colon (`:`) after the constructor's signature followed by the member field initializers, like this:

```
Hero() : magic_sword(2)
{
  // do other stuff to set up your hero
}
```

This will cause the `magic_sword` to be initialized using the `Sword::Sword(int)` constructor right away, which means you don't need to have a default `Sword::Sword()` constructor.

Read more: [Understanding Initialization Lists in C++](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

### Using pointers

Do you really want your `Sword` to belong exclusively to your `Hero`? Can your `Hero` maybe drop a `Sword`, and another `Hero` picks it up?

In this case, you probably don't want your `Hero` to have a `Sword` as a member - instead, you'd want a *pointer* to a `Sword` that he's currently holding - which can then maybe be `nullptr` if he's, for example, not holding a sword!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This works. I didn't want to use pointers yet - they are scary when you come from a functional language.

Comment: @Kaligule if the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to the vote buttons.

Comment: And yeah, pointers can be scary. C++ is a big pond, you'll get there eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Sword` class does not have a constructor with no parameters. At the beginning of `Hero()` (before the opening `{`), the members that are not specified in the [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) get default constructed.

Try this:

```
Hero() : magic_sword(2) {
};
```

Or you can add another constructor to `Sword` that takes no parameters.

```
Sword(){
    lenght = -1;
};
```

Comment: You forgot the : between () and meters.

Comment: `meters` is not a member of `Hero`, this should not compile

Comment: @AndreiAndrey oops :) (not doing enough C++ lately)

Comment: @Treeston fixed.

Comment: Now `meters` is undefined. See my answer for a more concise explanation of the problem.

Comment: @Treeston removed `meters` and replaces with `2`.

Comment: Why use assignment and not initialization?

Comment: @AmiTavory For an `int`, I think it is a matter of preference but it could be done either way. I was just keeping changes to the existing code/style as small as possible. [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926795/1441)

Answer (score 1):

(Let me guess - you're coming from Java?)

Compiler is correct. `Sword` does not have a default constructor, and it's a problem.

By this point in the code,

```
public:
  Hero(){
    // This point.
```

C++ requires the `magic_sword` to have been constructed already. Unlike Java, there is no "null" value to use as default. The only way to construct a `Sword` by that point is to use a no-argument constructor, which the `Sword` does not have.

Of course, there is a way to make the code work. Here is the syntax:

```
public:
  Hero() : magic_sword(2) {

  }
```

This tells the compiler how to call the `Sword`'s constructor before the `Hero`'s constructor's body begins.

Note on your design: you likely need `magic_sword` to be some sort of pointer (raw, unique or refcounting). Unlike Java, `magic_sword` as written is not a reference to instance of `Sword` but an actual instance, wholly contained withing the `Hero` instance.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpfull. (I started programming with Java 5 years ago, but I have had much more python, since).

Comment: Python has the same approach: instance attributes are references, not actual instances embedded in the owner, right?